# Regarding the choice of Job Scheduler android

Tags: android, location, job-scheduling

I am new into android and am seeking some help.

I am building an app that requires me to perform location updates after every fifteen minutes. So, my question is: Is it a better option to use Job Scheduler, or shall I use Google API and set t=it to update after 15 minutes, and then work *onLocationChanged()*.

Please help me out in this. I need some expert advice.

Comment: Do these location updates do anything to the ui?

Comment: Yes.. once updated... the locations are updated on the ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the UI with the new location and not scheduling background tasks , go with LocationManager.

you may start polling in your Fragment's/Activity's `onStart` callback by using[LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) method.

In the `onStop` callback, you mayend listening/polling with [LocationManager#removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener))

And then let your implementation of [LocationListener#onLocationChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)) handle the rest.